# Error al ejecutar script usando BLOB SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, blob

Tengo el siguiente script que lo que hace es lo siguiente: saca el contenido de un word, y lo mete en un blob. Pero al ejecutarlo me salen estos errores.

> **-ORA22275 -> Localizador LOB no valido   -ORA06512 -> Linea 29
>   (DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, Dbms_Lob.File_Readonly);)**

```
DIRECTORY PLANTILLAS AS 'D:/Plantillas' 

DECLARE
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;
  v_blob   BLOB; 

  existe integer;
BEGIN
      v_blob := EMPTY_BLOB();

    SELECT MAX(id) INTO existe FROM plantillas WHERE NOMBRE = 'plantilla';

    IF(existe is null) THEN
      INSERT INTO plantillas_ex 
       (ID, NBYTES, BLOQUE, MIMETYPE)
      VALUES 
       (existe,135680,v_blob,'application/msword')
      RETURN BLOQUE INTO l_blob;
    END IF;

  l_bfile := BFILENAME('PLANTILLAS', 'plantilla1');
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, Dbms_Lob.File_Readonly);
  DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob,l_bfile,DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);
  COMMIT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
   RAISE;
END;
```

Si alguien puediera o pudiese orientarme en esto, se lo agradecería. 
Un saludo

----------------------------------------------------// SOLUCION \-----------------------------------------------------------

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY PLANTILLAS AS 'D:/Plantillas';


DECLARE
 l_bfile  BFILE;
 l_blob   BLOB;
 v_blob   BLOB;
 l_length integer;

 existe integer;
 existe_blp integer;
BEGIN
     v_blob := EMPTY_BLOB();

   SELECT MAX(id) INTO existe FROM SPAC_P_PLANTDOC WHERE NOMBRE = 'plantilla';
   SELECT ID INTO existe_blp FROM SPAC_P_BLP WHERE ID = existe;

   IF(existe is not null AND existe_blp <> existe) THEN
     INSERT INTO SPAC_P_BLP 
      (ID, NBYTES, BLOQUE, MIMETYPE)
     VALUES 
      (existe,0,v_blob,'application/msword')
     RETURN BLOQUE INTO l_blob;


     l_bfile := BFILENAME('PLANTILLAS', 'plantilla1.doc');
     DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, Dbms_Lob.File_Readonly);
     l_length := Dbms_Lob.getlength(l_bfile);
     DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob,l_bfile,DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));    
     DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

     update SPAC_P_BLP set nbytes = l_length where id = existe;


  END IF;


EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: Hola, mirate esta línea  `l_bfile := BFILENAME('PLANTILLAS', plantilla1');` Tienes una comilla al final de **plantilla**, no sé si es un error al copiarlo o lo tienes así en tu proyecto

Comment: Ha sido al copiarlo, y modificar el nombre, se me ha colado.

Comment: Prueba viendo sí existe el archivo primero: `l_bfile := BFILENAME('BOOK_TEXT','chapter01.txt');
   l_bfile_exist := DBMS_LOB.FILEEXISTS( l_bfile ) = 1;

   IF l_bfile_exist
   THEN
      DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN( l_bfile );       DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE( l_bfile );
   END IF;`

Comment: @Edu3D probe con eso, pero me sigue dando los mismos errores.

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 29?

Answer (score 1):

Yo veo dos cosas en este script:

La primera; el `IF(existe is null) THEN` no es al revés??? `IF(existe is not null) THEN` porque si `existe` es null como va a funcionar el insert?? Va a tronar porque es una llave nula. Creo que el insert se debe de hacer cuando sea no nulo.

La segunda que veo es; Estas leyendo archivos del disco. Mi pregunta es ¿Ya le diste permisos a tu usuario para que lea archivos del disco?
Esta instrucción nos permite manejar directorios dentro de la BD:`GRANT create any directory TO usuario;`

Una vez hecho eso tienes que hacer esto otro: 
Para crear el directorio se debe darle un nombre para utilizarlo dentro de la BD, en este ejemplo `xmldirectorio` y la ruta de la ubicación del directorio en el sistema operativo. Posteriormente se le dan permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución para poder utilizarlo.

`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDIRECTORIO AS 'C:\XSDs';`

`GRANT EXECUTE, READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY XMLDIRECTORIO TO usuario WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Una vez echo esto ya podrías usar en este ejemplo `XMLDIRECTORIO` para acceder al directorio.
Ya hiciste esto???

Comment: Si tenia permisos, y cierto es que el if estaba mal pero me seguia dando fallo, pero al final al hacer cambios y mas cambios me funciono, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Deberías compartir como lo solucionaste, a alguien mas le puede servir.